# yes no option with javascript delete function for a link

Tags: php, javascript

In 1stpage I have a table with full of data, and end of every row there is a delete link. When i click on that link, the link goes to another delete page where mysql delete query delete that particular data from database. That delete page redirect with the 1st page (location:1stpage). Now when i want to apply a javascript delete yes/no checking, every time it pops up with "Are you sure?" either i press yes or no the data is deleted from my table. I think the return false cannot working in this case. The code are in below. Please help me what should i do exactly.

Sorry for my bad english.
Thanks in advance.
1st page:

```
<?php
include "include.php";
?>

<script type="text/javascript">

function show_confirm()
{
var con = confirm("Are You Sure");
if (con ==true)
  {
  alert("You pressed OK!");
  }
else
  {
  alert("You pressed Cancel!");
  }
}


 </script> 
<table>
  <tr>
    <td align="center">EDIT OR DELETE DATA</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <table border="1">
      ?php
        if(isset($_POST['submit']))
        {
            $order = "UPDATE books SET author='$_POST[author]', title='$_POST[title]', price='$_POST[price]' WHERE isbn='$_POST[isbn]'";
            mysql_query($order) or die (mysql_error());
        }   

      $order = "SELECT * FROM books ORDER BY author" or die (mysql_error());
      $result = mysql_query($order);
      while ($row=mysql_fetch_array($result))
      {
        echo ("<tr>
                <td>$row[isbn]</td>
                <td>$row[author]</td>
                <td>$row[title]</td>
                <td>$row[price]</td>
                <td> <a href=\"editdata_form.php?isbn=$row[isbn]\"> Edit </a> </td>
                <td> <a href=\"delete.php?isbn=$row[isbn]\" onclick='show_confirm()'> Delete </a> </td>
              </tr>");
      }       

  ?>
      </table>
    </td>
   </tr>
</table>
```

the page where mysql delete query run :

```
<?php header("Location: editordeletedata.php"); ?>  
<p> <title>delete</title> </p>
<?php
include "include.php";
?>

<?php

if(isset($_GET['isbn']))
{
    $order = "DELETE FROM books WHERE isbn = '$_GET[isbn]'";
    mysql_query($order) or die (mysql_error());
}


?>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Look at this simple code snippet I wrote, should get you fixed up right.

```
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript">

function show_confirm() {
    return confirm("Are You Sure");
}
</script>
</head>
<body>
    <a href="http://www.google.com" onclick='return show_confirm();'> Google </a>
</body>
</html>
```

[**Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/ult_combo/AqqX6/)

Comment: I'd work that indenting a little more but this is an excellent answer, +1

Comment: As you commented in the other answer, the main point is the `return` inside the `onclick` handler, this way when the function returns false (when the user chooses "Cancel"), the click event is cancelled. I've added a fiddle as well, had to replace google by another example page as google is being a sissy and not loading inside JSFiddle's iframe. `:)`

Comment: yaapii!!!!..........its party time :D :D.....it is working. Thanks a lot dear Fiddle, and very much thanks for your explanation. Its short and effective. Have a nice day. :)

Answer (score 0):

Disable the delete link and move the redirection to the javascript function. The link should look like this:

```
<a href=\"javascript:void(0)\" onclick='show_confirm($row[isbn])'> Delete </a>
```

And the javascript function just like this:

```
function show_confirm(isbn)
{
if (confirm("Are You Sure"))
  {
  alert("You pressed OK!");
  location.replace('delete.php?isbn='+isbn);
  }
else
  {
  alert("You pressed Cancel!");
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't see any reason why return false will not work.

```
function show_confirm()
{
    if (confirm("Are You Sure"))
    {
      alert("You pressed OK!");
    }
    else
    {
        alert("You pressed Cancel!");
        return false;
    }
}
```

Comment: Bigger problem was the the onclick needed to 'return' the value as well: 
onclick="return show_confirm();" instead of onclick="show_confirm();"

Comment: Thank you codebins for your comment. Yes, its all about "return".